# jenkins pipeline should fail after "Compiled with the following type errors" this sentence occure

Tags: shell, jenkins-pipeline

HI i need help to write the jenkins pipeline if "Compiled with the following type errors" this sentence occure . pipeline should abort

i tried if (sh(npm run build:dev).exitCode != 0) then {

```
                echo 'npm build failed with compilation error'
               }
               else
                {
                     echo 'npm build succeeded'
               }
               fi
```

but i am not sure is it work or not showing syntex error "{" unexpected (expecting "then")

Answer (score 0):

You could, perhaps should, use a try catch block instead.

```bash
node {
    stage('example'){
        try {
            // npm install
            echo 'npm build succeeded'
        } catch (exc) {
            echo 'npm build failed with compilation error'
            throw exc
        }
    }
    
    stage('Next'){
        /* Will run if npm install works.
           Won't run if it fails as because of "throw exc"
        */
        echo "This was next"
    }
}
```

[Relevant documentation](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#flow-control)

Comment: hi. thnx for reply.. my existing set up is like...... s
            }
           steps {
               echo 'Dockerizing phase....'
               
               sh """
                   echo 'Installing npm ...'
                   npm install
                   npm run build:dev
                  
               """  with this set up giving   ""Compiled with the following type errors (you may want to check these before deploying your app): "" This Error and compiling build success .. my requirement to stop when this type of error shown in logs.. i hope you understand

Comment: Can you paste the full error message? If the result is non zero then the code I pasted will stop the pipeline. If you are trying to stop pipeline execution due to something in the logs that does not affect the exit code then you might need to parse the output. Maybe using something like sed.
PS when you paste code, its helpful to paste it in a code block.https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting